# Positioning text and images on a site grid

Tags: html, css, html5

I've just started learning HTML and CSS. Currently I'm creating a test site to practice with.

I'm just after an early idea if the principles I'm using are correct. The below is an snippet from the main body of my HTML code. It's just about positioning text and images on a grid at the moment. I seem to be using a lot of `div`s with IDs in the CSS for styling etc.

Some of the alt text is work in progress and repeated currently hence why it repeats.

Can someone tell me if the structure is ok, or not and what I'd need to do to change this?

```
<div id="topmenu" class="grid_4">
    <a href="www.bbc.com">About Us &nbsp &nbsp</a><a href="www.bbc.com">Our Cheeses &nbsp &nbsp</a><a href="www.bbc.com">Contact Us</a>
</div>

<div id="quote_one" class="grid_4">
    <p>"QUOTE 1 - We really love the taste of your cheese, we will be back for more"</p>
</div>

<div id="logo" class="grid_4">
    <img src="logo.jpg" alt="This is the company logo">
</div>

<div id="quote_two" class="grid_4">
    <p>"QUOTE 2 - We really love the taste of your cheese, we will be back for more"</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Validating your code should be your first step if you want to do things the "right" way (ie. you are mising a semicolon for your HTML entities, which the validator would have caught for you).

Comment: I've found this website to be particularly helpful in learning about the new HTML5 elements:  http://html5doctor.com/

Answer (score 3):

**a)** Don’t use `&nbsp &nbsp` to separate the navigation links. You could use `ul` instead (and style it with CSS `display:inline;` if required):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="…">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="…">Our Cheeses</a></li>
  <li><a href="…">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

**b)** `div` has no meaning. You should only use `div` if there is no other appropriate, "narrower" element. If you are quoting something, use `blockquote`. If you have a navigation menu, use `nav`. Of course you can use `div` in addition to those appropriate elements, if needed.

**c)** This is not an error, but an opinion-based advice: If you don’t have a strong reason, don’t add `id` attributes just because you need a styling hook. You could use the `class` attribute even for what some call "unique" elements. Good reasons to use `id` are: in-page links (fragment identifier) and, sometimes, JavaScript hooks.

Answer (score 2):

You should get into a habit of adding the protocol to your anchors, as it can sometimes lead to confusing effects, such as in this case:

```
<a href="www.website.com">Website!</a>
```

Let's say, the site where that code is on is called http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php

Guess where you would go when clicking the `<a>`? 
You would be directed to the address http://www.mywebsite.com/www.website.com instead of the intended http://www.website.com

Also, if you are going to do XTHML or HTML5, you should close your IMG tags like this:
`<img src="logo.jpg" alt="This is the company logo" />`
Notice the '/' in the end.

The same applies to any tags that do not use a closing tag:
`<p>This has a closing tag</p>`
`<input type="text" name="textField" value="No closing tag in me!" />`

A very good tool for testing your HTML is the official validator from W3C:
http://validator.w3.org

Comment: The trailing slash for empty elements like img, br, input, etc. are optional for HTML5.  They're only required for XHTML (since it is a dialect of XML).

Comment: It is still good practice to close all tags though.